# How to program favorite keys

Tags: logitech-keyboard

On my keyboard, there are three favorite keys, but I don't remember how to set them.

I have put in a wrong address and don't remember how to bring the settings up.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you help us a little and tell us which keyboard you have, which operating system you're running, and if you installed any special software for your keyboard?

Comment: Pat, that information would be helpful - What exactly is your KB model? It should be on the bottom. If you have already answered your question or come to some other sort of arrangement, please answer this one or delete it. Thanks!